# JSON gerado pelo json_encode dá erro no caractere "{"

Tags: php, json

Não entendo o que está acontecendo, estou usando uma função `json_encode` no PHP
e o que ela retorna é inválido?!

Eu estou usando o [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) como validador, e ele afirma que o erro é no primeiro `{`. Se eu substituo esse caractere por outro `{`, ele diz que é valido. Será que estou usando alguma codificação incorreta no arquivo? Aos meus olhos o caractere parece exatamente igual. Segue abaixo o retornado a função:

```
{
   "status": 1,
   "page": "1",
   "content": "foo",
   "hasNext": true
}
```

Aparentemente existe algo errado entre esse caractere -> { <-(copiado) e esse -> { <- (digitado), mas parece ser o mesmo... Estou ficando maluco, alguém tem alguma suposição do que pode ser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tudo indica que seu PHP está emitindo mais alguma coisa antes do `{`. Verifique se seu arquivo está salvo como UTF-8 com BOM (byte-order mask), pois o BOM invalidaria o JSON.

Para verificar, abra num editor como Notepad++ e salve o arquivo como UTF-8 sem BOM.